# Unable to view Salesforce survey response

Tags: salesforce-survey

When I go to survey invitation and click view response, I am getting below error. I have tried creating new survey and tried in different sandboxes. But facing the same issue. Is anyone else facing the same problem?

[image: View Response]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue for Summer 21 release and will be fixed in Winter 22.

Link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001U4pkQAC&title=view-survey-responses-action-on-surveyresponse-errors-out-with-internal-server-error-stack-trace-133327422

> View Survey Response action on SurveyResponse record option in the
> Survey Invitations does not work and errors out with internal server
> error stack trace (133327422).